# How to add text into a Label in a TableView

Tags: java, database, javafx, label, tableview

I have a TableView in which I have an clients emails column. In the emails column there is a Label called emails that should get populated with emails from the database depending on the column in which the Label is on.

My try so far is as follows:

```
public class ClientsListTableView {

    List clientsTableInitItems = new RetrieveClients().retrieveClients();

    private final TableView table;
    private Label emails;

    public ClientsListTableView(TableView table) {
        this.table = table;
        this.clientsListTableView();
    }

    private void clientsListTableView() {
        TableColumn clientEmails = new TableColumn();

        clientEmails.setMaxWidth(368);

        // Client emails column
        clientEmails.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<NewClientPOJO, String>("otherNames"));
        clientEmails.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<NewClientPOJO, String>, TableCell<NewClientPOJO, String>>() {
            @Override
            public TableCell<NewClientPOJO, String> call(TableColumn<NewClientPOJO, String> param) {
                final TableCell<NewClientPOJO, String> cell = new TableCell<NewClientPOJO, String>() {

                    @Override
                    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);
                        if (!isEmpty()) {

                            new ClientItemAction();
                            emails.getStyleClass().add("table-text-allign-top-left");

                            VBox vbTable = new VBox();
                            vbTable.getChildren().add(emails);

                            setGraphic(vbTable);
                        }
                    }
                };
                return cell;
            }
        });

        // Add columns
        itemsListsTableView.getColumns().add(clientEmails);

        // Add items to TableView and draw
        itemsListsTableView.setItems((ObservableList) clientsTableInitItems);
    }

    // ItemAction Class
    private class ClientItemAction extends TableCell<NewClientPOJO, String> {

        ClientItemAction() {
            this.clientItemAction();
        }
        VBox vBItemAction = new VBox();

        void clientItemAction() {
            int selectdIndex = getTableRow().getIndex();

            NewClientPOJO selectedRecord = (NewClientPOJO) table.getItems().get(selectdIndex);
            new ManageItems().deleteItems(selectedRecord.getClientID(), NewClientPOJO.class);
            emails.setText(String.valueOf(selectedRecord.getClientID()));

        }
    }
}
```

The method that reads from the database in a Class `ManageItems`:

```
/* Method to  READ items */
public List<?> listItems(String query) {
    List itemsList = null;
    try {
        session.beginTransaction();
        itemsList = session.createQuery(query).list();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (session != null) {
            // tx.rollback();
        }
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return itemsList;
}
```

I, however get the following error with this approach.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: wakiliproject.Listings.ClientsListTableView$ClientItemAction
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
```

Please help me get items into my Labels embedded in the TableView Columns. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What line gives this error?

Comment: Hi [user1803551](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1803551/user1803551). Thanks for taking the time to look at my question. Would you please mind taking a look at [this new one here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23824061/how-to-get-the-tablerow-index-javafx-tableview) I just posted. I kind of figured where I was going wrong, but can't get the whole thing to work. Thank you again.

Comment: If you figured out the answer, post it as an answer for others to see. Also say what line gives the error so the question will be legitimate. Finally, reply to users with a simple @username and not "Hi username" with a link.

Comment: Hi @user1803551. Thanks for the response and advise, but [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23835151/how-to-add-nested-table-rows-in-a-tableview) is what I'm after. Hope you can help. I haven't completely solved the problem, but it's quite clear now where the problem seems to arise from.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you place a label into a table cell at all?

First off, `TableView` can be parameterized.

Second, Hibernate should be returning a list with an object type.

Once you have that, you can create an `ObservableList` using `FXCollections.observableArrayList(collection);` After that is created, you can set the table's items to that list.

After those objects are in the table, all you need to do is implement a `CellValueFactory`.

Check out Oracle's tutorial on `TableView` [Here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm)

Comment: Hi @LinkXXII. Thanks for the response, but [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23835151/how-to-add-nested-table-rows-in-a-tableview) is what I'm after. Hope you can help.