# How to get the TableRow index (JavaFx TableView)

Tags: java, database, javafx, tableview, tablerow

I have a TableView in which I have a clients emails column. In the emails column there is a Label called emails that should get populated with emails from the database depending on the column in which the Label is on.

The text is retrieved from a database and therefore, to get a specific email address, I need to get the row index, and query for that particular email with something like:

```
"SELECT email from Clients WHERE clientID = " + rowItemRecord.getClientID());
```

My approach so far is as follows:

```
int itemRowIndex = getTableRow().getIndex();
NewClientPOJO rowItemRecord = (NewClientPOJO) table.getItems().get(itemRowIndex);

// Then
"SELECT email from Clients WHERE clientID = " + rowItemRecord.getClientID());
```

This doesn't work. I get a null pointer.

The Question is:

How can I get the TableView TableRow index.... A better approach that will work.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you must first start your index:
Try first wiht "if ... hasNext()" then index=...
hasNext check if a value exists, and then start the index at this value.
I'm not sure of the exact name of the method "hasnext", I let you find this by yourself :)
Niko

Comment: Hi @Hermios. Thanks for the response, but [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23835151/how-to-add-nested-table-rows-in-a-tableview) is what I'm after. Hope you can help.